# Why is ALTER faster than UPDATE (for full table rewrites)?

Tags: postgresql, update, alter-table, postgresql-12

Let's create a garbage table..

```
CREATE TABLE foo
  AS SELECT x::text FROM generate_series(1,20e6) AS t(x); 
Time: 14077.654 ms (00:14.078)
```

Now, let's look at boring `UPDATE`,

```
UPDATE foo SET x = 'foo';
Time: 22239.050 ms (00:22.239)
```

Compared with `ALTER`,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ALTER COLUMN x
  SET DATA TYPE text
  USING 'foo';
Time: 9480.027 ms (00:09.480)
```

It's approximately twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Both do rather different things under the hood.

`ALTER TABLE` takes an exclusive lock on the table and rewrites it. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES)

> The rewriting forms of `ALTER TABLE` are not MVCC-safe. After a table
> rewrite, the table will appear empty to concurrent transactions, if
> they are using a snapshot taken before the rewrite occurred. See
> [Section 13.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-caveats.html) for more details.

`UPDATE` only takes a write lock on affected rows (all in this case) and *adds* new row versions to the table, roughly doubling its physical size (unless it can reuse dead space). Concurrent readers can proceed happily.

Table-rewriting forms of `ALTER TABLE` do not write to the WAL. `UPDATE`, OTOH, *also* has to write to the WAL first. That's also why `UNLOGGED` tables can `UPDATE` in roughly half the time: no WAL by definition.

The fiddle demonstrates some effective differences:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d3ad6c164bdbe924818a9b6c8fe75be5)*